# Metaplex : How to distinguish fake nft from real one with right collection

Tags: web3.js, metaplex, nft, metaplex-js

i process transactions and get metadata of nft but sometimes there are many fake one but i can't distinguish if it's fake or not, so i put them in the real collections.

Let's look at some details.

let's look at this one : https://magiceden.io/item-details/HUoMfa1L33XADRoEmczGSKrXHZ6D8tPzaWrFoVnfJocW

This is unverified collection and obviously the collection field in metadata is null

```
collection: null,
collectionDetails: null
```

I know that's cool but now let's look at this one https://magiceden.io/item-details/J8i5Lffme9tiAsrxonT3xpdJQG17aVmyeAPCHby8fweu

This collection should be verified but from metadata the collection is null

```
collection: null,
collectionDetails: null
```

This can be faked easily and i don't know how can i distinguish fake nft from real one.

Also this one is fake but from data i can't distinguish if it's fake or not.

```
json: {
    name: 'DeGod #5047',
    symbol: 'DGOD',
    description: '10,000 of the most degenerate gods in the universe.',
    seller_fee_basis_points: 999,
    image: 'https://metadata.degods.com/g/5046-dead.png',
    external_url: 'https://degods.com/',
    attributes: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ],
    collection: { name: 'DeGods', family: 'Godplex' },
    properties: { files: [Array], category: 'image', creators: [Array] }
  }
```

Anyone know how to get if the nft is fake or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 ways to tell if a NFT is real:

1. The official collection has released a hashlist containing the address of every NFT in the collection.
2. You know what is the first verified creator (it can be more than 1 first verified creator, because NFTs can be minted from differents Candy Machines, each one having its own First verified creator).
3. You know what is the [Metaplex Certified Collection](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/certified-collections) address (onchain
   collection) of the official NFT.

For example Degods official onchain collection is `6XxjKYFbcndh2gDcsUrmZgVEsoDxXMnfsaGY6fpTJzNr` so if you want to check if your Degod is rial, then you have to verify its onchain collection with the above address and verified true.

[image: example official degod]

Also, Degod were minted from 2 Candy Machines, so they have 2 first verified creator that has to be checked (if you dont want to use onchain collection) (1st `9MynErYQ5Qi6obp4YwwdoDmXkZ1hYVtPUqYmJJ3rZ9Kn`, 2nd `8RMqBV79p8sb51nMaKMWR94XKjUvD2kuUSAkpEJTmxyx`).

In both cases you should ask the team for this fields in order to know what exactly the official values are.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well, you need to find a list of every mints (so the 10000 for Degods) and check them individually

Would be interested if anyone knows another way of doing this!